# How to upgrade Vista Home Premium to Vista Ultimate with a Full (not Upgrade) Copy of Ultimate?

Tags: windows-vista

I am running Vista Home Premium. I have a full license of Vista Ultimate in a new box (in other words, it is a full ready-to-install copy, not an Upgrade edition). How do I upgrade from my existing system from Home to Ultimate inline (as if I had an Upgrade edition) without losing my data?

It is not clear to me what will happen if I let it rip. In other words, how "smart" will the install be, like will it notice that there's a perfectly good install of Vista Basic already and ask me if I simply wish to upgrade to Ultimate - or will it pave over my existing installation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm fairly sure you need their "anytime upgrade" versions to upgrade from one version to another.

[More information here.](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-vista/get/anytime-upgrade-overview.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

The upgrade is *supposed* to work.  It seems like [this](http://news.softpedia.com/news/Microsoft-You-Cannot-Upgrade-Vista-SP1-to-a-Vista-RTM-83159.shtml) is the problem you're hitting.  Do you have a Vista service pack installed (SP1 or SP2)?  How new is the installation media that you're trying to upgrade to?

Answer (score 1):

Do a backup of important stuff and just install a fresh copy, upgrading is a joke, especially on 
Windows platforms.

I install fresh, I don't upgrade.